# How to generate a multi-columns table with the checkbox form insert in the first column?

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox

This is my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms

class MusicCheckboxForm(forms.Form):
    songs = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

I want use the forms.py file to produce the multi-columns table with the checkbox insert to the first column, But I don't want hard code `<input type="checkbox" ...>` to the template.
And I want the multi-columns look like this:

```
All song artist album genre date
[]  aaa  Smith  fdaf  rock 2001
[]  bbb  Davis  fdsaf blue 2002
[]  ccc  Doe    dfaj  sjaf 2000
```

The snippet of my template looks like this:

```
<table class="list" summary="musics">
  <caption>
    music list
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <th>All</th>
    <th>song</th>
    <th>artist</th>
    <th>album</th>
    <th>genre</th>
    <th>date</th>
  </tr>
  {% for info in all_info %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- I want put checkbox here -->
    </td>

    {% if info|hasattr:"title" %}
      <td>{{ info.title }}</td>
    {% else %}
      <td></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if info|hasattr:"artist" %}
      <td>{{ info.artist }}</td>
    {% else %}
      <td></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if info|hasattr:"album" %}
      <td>{{ info.album }}</td>
    {% else %}
      <td></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if info|hasattr:"genre" %}
      <td>{{ info.genre }}</td>
    {% else %}
      <td></td>
    {% endif %}

    {% if info|hasattr:"date" %}
      <td>{{ info.date }}</td>
    {% else %}
      <td></td>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`django-tables2` simplifies transforming data into HTML tables. It does for HTML tables what `django.forms` does for HTML forms..

See this : http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I am trying it, see whether I can do it.

Comment: So django-tables + django-filter and you've got your admin changelist. This is fantastic !

Comment: The tutorial say: "instantiate the table and pass in the data", Is the data is a tuples list?